# engine used when creating Hive table with joins using Spark SQL

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I am not sure from documentation if when creating an Hive table using HiveContext from Spark, will it use the Spark engine or the standard Hive mapreduce job to perform the task?

```
val sc = new SparkContext()
val hc = new HiveContext(sc)

hc.sql("""
    CREATE TABLE db.new_table
    STORED AS PARQUET
    AS SELECT
        field1,
        field2,
        field3
    FROM db.src1 
        JOIN db.src2
        ON (x = y)
"""
)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Spark 1.6
```

Spark SQL supports Apache Hive using `HiveContext`. It uses the `Spark SQL execution engine` to work with data stored in Hive.

```
above Spark 2.x
```

> val spark = SparkSession .builder() .appName( "SparkSessionExample" ) .config( "spark.sql.warehouse.dir" , warehouseLocation) .`enableHiveSupport()` .getOrCreate()

Comment: Answer not clear enough. E.g. Hivecontext not required with Spark 2. Spark has own APIs or Hive can use SPARK as engine. Writes vs. Reads?

Comment: @thebluephantom Yes I know I can set spark as engine in Hive, but I was asking explicitly for code written inside a Spark application. Thanks anyway for pointing out.

Comment: But my answer covers it all. I think

Answer (score 0):

When doing this now, SPARK will use SPARK APIs and not MR. Hivecontext need not be explicitly referenced as is deprecated, even in spark-submit / program mode.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. HiveContext is required to read data from Hive tables, SQLContext does not work, at least in Spark 1.6.0 which I am using.

Comment: Things evolve so you need to be clear. Spark 2.x is where you should be